# Which places in India does the authentic "pitru vidhi" happen?

Tags: india, pitru

*Pitru Vidhi* mainly deals with doing ceremony for one's own paternal family ancestors. Usually this leads to their peace. If not done properly then these same ancestors will create minor/major family related problems. Such problems are indication of pending "pitru vidhi".

**Which places [especially in India], the genuine "Pitru Vidhi" happens?**
(Stressing on "genuine" as, this ceremony might be happening at all the cities/towns but mostly they are not up to the mark. Read below passage for more info.)

To avoid opinions, kindly provide some reference for that place if possible. For example, "Prachi, Gujarat, India" is so famous for "Pitru Vidhi", that it is advertised in [Tripadvisor](https://www.tripadvisor.in/ShowUserReviews-g2282347-d6833564-r389248743-Prachi_Tirth-Somnath_Gir_Somnath_District_Gujarat.html) as well.

---

#### More info

On a personal note, A best friend of mine had this experience. His family was never having any boy child. If it were born, then would die in short span.
Then they went to a small village called Prachi for this ceremony. A big circle was made & all the families belonging to their lineage were sitting there. The priests started chanting of various Mantra-s since early morning. Slowly towards the noon, a recently wed bride who was very new to the family started showing some symptoms of possession. Within short time she exhibited various "pitru"-s and their talks which she never knew. Few examples:

- One pitru died due to fire accident, but it couldn't scream. So it came to her body & just screamed
- One pitru was not offered water; it possessed her body, drank lot of water and went
- One pitru wanted to give one necklace to an acquaintance; That pitru was convinced somehow & went
- One pitru wanted to treat everyone with a feast; They somehow arranged for everyone and that also went
- ...

Later I heard that this issue was resolved to an extent. My friend seeing all these is as good as I am seeing, as we are very close friends for 20+ years.

Comment: तस्माच्छाद्भं प्रयत्नेन अमायां कर्तुमर्हति |
यदि श्राद्भं प्रकुर्वन्ति पुत्राद्यास्य बान्धवा: ||54|| 
उद्भता ये गयाश्राद्धे ब्रह्मलोकंच तै सह ||
भजन्ते क्षुप्तिपासा वा न तेषां जायते क्वचित ||55||

Therefore , one should carefully perform shradha on the Amavasya day. If son or relatives perform shardha at Gaya , they uplift their ancestors from lower regions and themselves enjoy Brahmaloka together with the manes. They never suffer from thrust and hunger.  -GP chapter 10

Comment: Also at various towns which are situated at banks of the Ganges.  e.g. Haridwar , Badrinath . Also  at  Trayambakeshwar Nashik (MH) where river Godavari is.

Comment: @SwiftPushkar, you have good info about this. Kindly post it as an answer.

Comment: hmm but I have only one ref. (Gaya) with me. I will search for the other places and then will try to post a answer.

Comment: @iammilind better avoid places like Gaya and har ki pauri etc.. most of the priests there do not know rituals properly. either take someone with you or approach a well learned peirst.

Answer (score 7):

> Which places in India does the authentic “pitru vidhi” happen?

IMO, while this question can't have answers from the scriptures but the following can have:

> Which is the best place for doing pitru related works (like pinda
>   dana)?

The best is without doubt Gaya however there are many other places which are considered sacred pitru sthalas.

> **All the departed Manes, afraid of hell, seek it, thinking, ' The son
>   who will go to Gaya would be our rescuer**.' (20) One should desire for
>   many sons, for if one happens to go to Gaya", or one happens perform'
>   a Horse-Sacrifice, or to dedicate a Neela Bull.
>
> The deceased, for whom a bull is let loose on the' eleventh day, is
>   released from the region of the dead, and goes to that of the Pitris.
>   (9)
>
> **Many sons should be sought for, because one of them at least may
>   happen to go to Gaya**, or celebrate a horse sacrifice, or dedicate a
>   Neela bull. (10)
>
> **Vrihaspati Smriti, Chapter 1 verses**

Similarly from the Likhita Smriti's chapter 1:

> If one, after entering Beneras, leaves that place on any occasion and
>   goes elsewhere, the Bhutas (spirits) laugh, striking their palms,
>   amongst themselves,
>
> **The person naming whom one offers a pinda at
>   Gaya, goes to the celestial region, if stationed in a hell ; and
>   attains to emancipation, if residing in the celestial region.** (12)
>
> One takes him, whether he be his own relative or an out-sider, to the
>   eternal region of Brahman, **by naming whom he offers a pinda at any
>   place in the sacred shrine of Gaya.** (13')

Another verse from Katyayana Smriti's chapter 29:

> Some learned men speak of the superiority of the offering of Pindas,
>   for, it is seen that, **at holy places chiefly at Gaya, merely Pindas
>   are offered**. (9)

Greatness of [Gaya Tirtha from Kurma PurAna](http://www.kamakoti.org/kamakoti/kurmapurana/bookview.php?chapnum=20):

> Gayaa Tirtham param guhyam Pitrunaam chaativallabham,
>
> Krutwaa pinda pradaanam tu na bhuyovjaayatey narah
>
> Sakrud Gayaabhigamanam krutwaa pidam dadaati yah,
>
> Taaritam tarastena yaasyanti Paramaa Gatim
>
> ...........
>
> **Gaya Kshetra is one of the most beloved Tirthaas of Pitru Devataas and
>   human beings who offer Pindas to Pitras have no rebirth. Even if once
>   the sacred deed of ‘Pinda Pradana’ is executed at Gaya, Pitraas would
>   be freed from Narakaas and are forwarded to Parama Gati.** At Gaya the
>   most hallowed signs of Rudra Deva’s feet are imprinted on a Stone and
>   offering Pindaas there would most certainly bless the Karta and redeem
>   the Pitraas. Even while a person  is in a position to visit Gaya and
>   perform the Pinda Pradana, he is lazy or careless and  the Pitras
>   would feel disgruntled and dissatisfied. The Pitraas would vow:
>
> Yadi syaat paatakopetah swaadharmarati varjitah,
>
> Gayaam yaasyati yah kaschit sosmaan santaarayishyati.
>
> ..........
>
> **Even if a person in my Vamshaa were highly sinful for any reason and
>   did not observe ‘Swadharama’ but had visited Gaya Tirtha and gave away
>   Pinda Pradana, he would still be liberated!**

The PDF [Essence of Knowledge of Numbers hosted by the Kamakoti.org](https://www.kamakoti.org/kamakoti/articles/ESSENCE-OF-KNOWLEDGE-OF-NUMBERS.pdf) gives few names of holy Pitru Kshetras apart from Gaya:

> **Yatra Shraddhas**: are specifically related to visits of Punya Tirtha Kshestras like Gaya sheersha, Akshaya Vata, Brahma Kapaala,
>   Gangaasaagara Sangama Kushaavarta, Bilva, Neela Parvata, Prayaga,
>   Kubjaagra, Bhrugutunga, Kedara, Mahaalaya, Amarakataka Narmada,
>   Yamuna, Ganga, 85 Ganga dwara, Lalika, Sugandha, Shakambari, Phalguni
>   Tirtha, Maha Ganga, Tantu vikaashrama, Kumara dharva prabhava,
>   Saraswati, Kuru Kshetra, Naimishaaranya, Varanaasi, Agastya Ahrama,
>   Kanvaashrama, Pushkarini, Gokarna, Narmada, Godavari, Krishna, Kaveri,
>   Gomati,Vetravati, Vipasha, Vitasti, Shatadu, Chandrabhaaga, Iravati,
>   Kaanchi, Pancha nadi teera, Kaushaki, Saryu, Shona, Jyoti ratha,
>   Uttara Manasa, Badaba, Saoptarcha, Vishnu Paada, Swarga maga pradesha,

Comment: Wonderful info.

Comment: Thanks AjitDas @ajitdas

Answer (score 3):

Gaya is believed to be an apt destination for performing shraadha for its supposedly purgation powers. The place has been mentioned in both Ramayan and Mahabharat as Gayapuri. Pind daan is performed with the use of wheat and oat flour and mud balls. There are about 48 places currently in Gaya where pind daan is performed.

Comment: You should cite sources to back your answer.