# Shraddha Ritual - On Pindadaan and its offering locations

Tags: rituals, sraddha

I have heard that Pindadaan is given in Gaya. Why can't "any place" be suitable for Pindadaan? Does Gaya (or Pinda-eligible places) contain any sort of spiritual momentum or subtle spiritual forces, which transmit the offering to the departed soul?

Like for example Kumbha Mela is only held in the 4 places where Amrit was spilled. That's why Kumbha Mela cannot be held anywhere else.

Another example would be 51 Pithas of Sati's organs. No other place could be eligible for being qualified as Shakti Pith.

So, is there anything special about Gaya (or other Pinda-eligible places)?

Comment: There are other places but Gaya is the most recommended.. Like there are many holy rivers but Ganga is the holiest..like there are many Mokshapuris but Kashi is the foremost among them..same here..

Comment: That is my question, what makes a Mokshapuri, and what makes a Pindasthaan?

Comment: You can see my answer here: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/19971/4732